# How can I force a retry for Integrated Windows Authentication via Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, windows-authentication, wso2-identity-server

I am aware the IWA authenticator is primarily aimed for the SPNEGO authentication. My question is about falling back to the basic authentication.

When the SPNEGO negotiation header is not provided by the user (the user is not logged in as a domain user or the browser doesn't trust the site), the Waffle IWA falls back to the Basic authentication (which is ok).

The problem is, once the user enters invalid credentials, the IWA authenticator throws / displays an exception without any option to retry.

```
com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Win32Exception: The logon attempt failed
    waffle.windows.auth.impl.WindowsAuthProviderImpl.acceptSecurityToken(WindowsAuthProviderImpl.java:137)
    waffle.servlet.spi.NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider.doFilter(NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider.java:102)
    waffle.servlet.spi.SecurityFilterProviderCollection.doFilter(SecurityFilterProviderCollection.java:116)
    org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.iwa.servlet.IWAServelet.doPost(IWAServelet.java:89)
```

I believe in the previous version (5.0.0.SP1) the user could re-authenticate (a new pop-up window was displayed), however currently I am unable to validate it.

Is there a way to enforce / allow retrying the basic authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed a configuration of the tomcat web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
 <display-name>Security Constraint for IWA</display-name>
 <web-resource-collection>
  <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
  <url-pattern>/iwa/*</url-pattern>
  <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
  <http-method>GET</http-method>
  <http-method>POST</http-method>
  <http-method>PUT</http-method>
 </web-resource-collection>
 <auth-constraint>
  <role-name>Everyone</role-name>
 </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

in this case the basic authentication is asked and retried when failed